# MVC Routing : Under Subdomain Not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have 2 websites like one is actual and another one is in virtual directory. Its working fine on: www.mywebsite.com/AnotherWebsite initial loading.

But after initail loading when I am trying to filter using following method my **View** is returning back to **www.mywebsite.com/Home/Index** but I need to stay like  **www.mywebsite.com/AnotherWebsite/Home/Index**

```
public ActionResult Index(int? pageNumber, string categories) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(categories)) {
        Session["Categories"] = categories;
        pageNumber = 1;
    }
     if (sessionCategoriesValue != "all") { 
        return View("AnotherWebsite/Home/Index", results.ToPagedList(pageNumber ?? 1, 15));                         
    }
    else {
        return View(Url.Content("~/")+"AnotherWebsite/Home/Index", results.ToPagedList(pageNumber ?? 1, 15));       

    } 
}
```

But My paging is working fine like www.mywebsite.com/AnotherWebsite/Home/Index?pageNumber=2&categories=null

My MapRoute is like bellow  :

```
routes.MapRoute( name: "Default", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );
```

Could you please advice.

Comment: Not sure, but what if you simply changed your route mapping to `routes.MapRoute( name: "Default", url: "AnotherWebsite/{controller}/{action}/{id}"`... ?

Comment: Now trying; Thank you and I will let you know

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you tried RouteConfig.cs custom routing before?

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs

RouteConfig.cs:

```
public class RouteConfig {

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(name: "AnotherWebsite", url: "AnotherWebsite/{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }); // this route should take place on top of default routing
        routes.MapRoute(name: "Default", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

If this way don't satisfy enough, the url section on MapRoute is subject to change for whatever you want, as long as includes "{controller}/{action}/{id}" routing rule.

- Addendum edit -

Seems that the subdomain can be redirected by using Request.ServerVariables  (subDomain is your desired subdomain name):

Controller.cs

```
// Note: "HTTP_URL" contains encoded raw URL data
// If you want unencoded version one, use "UNENCODED_URL"
if (String.IndexOf(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_URL").ToUpper(), subDomain.ToUpper()) > 0) 
{
    return RedirectToAction("youractionname", "yourcontrollername", new { // your action parameters here });
}
```

or by using "Contains":

```
if (Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_URL").ToUpper().Contains(subDomain.ToUpper())) {
        return RedirectToAction("youractionname", "yourcontrollername", new { // your action parameters here });
}
```

If the controller solution won't work, use IIS rewrite URL:

```
<rule name="YourRule" enabled="true">
<match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="- insert your subdomain regex pattern here-" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="yourdomain.ext/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" /> 
</rule>
```

Reference: https://host4asp.net/top-iis-rewrite-rules/

Comment: hin @Tetsuya Yamamoto still not working; do I have to do anything in controller

Comment: Not understanding why its going back to 
http://localhost/Home/Index?pageNumber=1&categories=xls; When choosing filtering

Comment: Added the controller solution and IIS rewrite rule example on edited post. I hope that can solve your redirect problem.